# perf counters are not available on this device when running stress-ng

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, perf

When I running stress-ng with --perf option, it shows this:

```
root@1f5f41f13d4b:/usr/lib/linux-tools# stress-ng --cpu 1 --timeout 2s --perf
stress-ng: info:  [4170] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu
stress-ng: info:  [4170] cache allocate: default cache size: 4096K
stress-ng: info:  [4170] successful run completed in 2.03s
stress-ng: info:  [4170] perf counters are not available on this device
```

I installed the linux-tools-generic package and found the perf tool. I ran the stress-ng and it had the same error. The linux system is Ubuntu 16.04. 
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Also, read the man page.

Comment: @Zulan it is a question related to system performance test and I am not aware stackoverflow doesn't allow system performance test related question. Anyway, I finally figured out the cause of issue: there is a Linux kernel setting to control this. But because I am running this inside docker container, this setting can only be changed on the host and it can not be changed inside a container.

Comment: @TravisGu What Kernel setting are you referring to?

Answer (score -2):

Try it with sudo like this:

sudo stress-ng --cpu 1 --timeout 2s --perf